# How to get values of a column without knowing the column type

Tags: java, database, jdbc

I am creating a query dynamically based on a user choosing fields to be displayed in the result. The problem is that when data is to be retrieved from the database I normally use `getXXX()` methods to retrieve the appropriate type. But in this case I do not know what the appropriate type is since the columns are randomly chosen.

Is there any way that I can get data in string format without specifying the data type XXX? I am using MySQL and Servlets.

Comment: doesn't `getXXX().toString()` work?

Comment: @deadlock - `getXXX` is a synonym for the cluster of methods (getDate, getBytes, getFloat etc). It's not a real method and the OP is asking about alternatives to using specific get methods when he doesn't know the underlying type.

Comment: yes it could but then I hava to know xxx beforehand...want to save that effort.

Answer (score 12):

You can use the generic [getObject](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getObject%28int%29) method :

> Gets the value of the designated column in the current row of this
>   ResultSet object as an Object in the Java programming language.
>
> This method will return the value of the given column as a Java
>   object. The type of the Java object will be the default Java object
>   type corresponding to the column's SQL type, following the mapping for
>   built-in types specified in the JDBC specification. If the value is an
>   SQL NULL, the driver returns a Java null.

Comment: thanx.I think it will help.

Comment: Why not simply `getString()` if all he wants is a String?

Answer (score 1):

First, Get `ResultRetMetadata then`, use it's method named as `getColumnTypeName(int indexOfCol)` to get it's type, then compare it to the datatypes using if else and use appropriate method `getxxx()`.

```java
    import java.sql.Types;
        // your code....
          ResultSetMetaData rsmd = resultset.getMetaData();
          int n = rsmd.getColumnCount();
          for(int i = 1; i <=n; i++){
              if(rsmd.getColumnTypeName(i) == Types.INTEGER){
                    System.out.println(resultset.getInt(i));
               }
              else if(rsmd.getColumnTypeName(i) == Types.VARCHAR){
                    System.out.println(resultset.getString(i));
               }
              // and so on ...
          }
        }
```

http://www.java2s.com/example/java-api/java/sql/types/other-0.html
Can Checkout this page for further reference :)

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, you can simply use `getString()` if you want the result in a Java String object. I think the MySQL driver takes care of deserializing the byte stream in whatever Java object you specify via `getXXX()`. Given the following init script:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS thing;

CREATE TABLE thing (
  a_int int,
  a_string text,
  a_date date
);

INSERT INTO thing (a_int, a_string, a_date)
   VALUES ('1234', 'Hello world', CURRENT_DATE() );
```

and the code:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    MysqlDataSource db = new MysqlDataSource();
    db.setDatabaseName("test");
    Connection conn = db.getConnection("test", "test");

    ResultSet res = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM thing").executeQuery();
    res.next();
    System.out.println("Get a int as a string: " + res.getString("a_int"));

}
```

It simply prints `Get a int as a string: 1234`. You can even get the `a_date` column as a Java `int`, and it's converted to `2013` on my machine. So it appears that the binding happens **after** the driver has retrieved an untyped stream of bytes from the server. Sometimes the conversion fails, for example if you try `getInt()` on the `TEXT` column.